# PostgreSQL query which return metrics joining different tables need to be more efficient and fast

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that can be seen on this fiddle and I'm relatively new to PSQL, having a few months of experience.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=16bfc0ab881602bac8847dded13d6de3)

The link to the third party is to show the result of it otherwise would be difficult to visualize it here.

```
WITH statuses_flow AS (
    SELECT
        c.id,
        c.study_id,
        c.site_id,
        s.type AS status_type,
        s.timestamp AS status_from,
        sa.type,
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY s.candidate_id,
            s.timestamp) AS row_no
    FROM
        public.candidates c
        JOIN public.statuses s ON s.candidate_id = c.id
        JOIN public.statuses sa ON sa.candidate_id = c.id
            AND sa.id in(
            SELECT
                max(id)
            FROM public.statuses
        GROUP BY
            candidate_id)
    WHERE
        c.study_id in('INIT1')
        AND c.site_id in('Test1')
        AND sa.type != 'ANONYMISED' ORDER BY
            row_no ASC
)
SELECT
    statuses_flow.id, statuses_flow.study_id AS "studyId", statuses_flow.site_id AS "siteId", statuses_flow.status_type AS "statusType", statuses_flow.status_from AS "statusFrom", next_status.status_from AS "statusTo", CASE WHEN next_status.status_from IS NULL THEN
        NULL
    ELSE
        (
        SELECT
            created_at AS first_contact
        FROM
            public.activities
        WHERE
            candidate_id = statuses_flow.id
            AND TYPE in('PHONE', 'SMS', 'EMAIL')
            AND created_at BETWEEN statuses_flow.status_from
            AND next_status.status_from ORDER BY
                created_at FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)
    END AS "first_contact"
FROM
    statuses_flow
    LEFT JOIN statuses_flow next_status ON statuses_flow.id = next_status.id
        AND statuses_flow.row_no + 1 = next_status.row_no
WHERE
    statuses_flow.status_type in('PENDING_SITE', 'PENDING_CALLCENTER', 'INCOMPLETE', 'REJECTED_CALLCENTER', 'REJECTED_SITE', 'CONSENTED')
ORDER BY
    statuses_flow.id,
    statuses_flow.status_from
```

This query collects and returns some metrics joining 3 tables about candidates being in a specific status during a medical study process.

The query in the real life is very slow and needs some adjustments to be written better.

The indexes are already applied on the original DB but still would be useful to find a better way.

The section of the query which I'm not convinced at this point is lines 29 to 42 from the DB fiddle link above.

I was wondering if by any chance could be changed to use a left join or another method to make a better performance.

It is returning per every candidate something as for example for one candidate the table below

| id | studyId | siteId | statusType | statusFrom | statusTo | first_contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Study1 | Site1 | INCOMPLETE | 2021-07-20 09:30:52.101055+00 | 2021-07-20 09:31:53.568346+00 | NULL |
| 1 | Study1 | Site1 | PENDING_CALLCENTER | 2021-07-20 09:31:53.568346+00 | 2021-07-20 09:35:34.171876+00 | 2021-07-20 09:31:55.849+00 |
| 1 | Study1 | Site1 | PENDING_SITE | 2021-07-20 09:35:34.171876+00 | 2021-07-20 09:52:42.185163+00 | 2021-07-20 09:35:56.642+00 |
| 1 | Study1 | Site1 | REJECTED_SITE | 2021-07-20 09:53:08.874271+00 | NULL | NULL |

To explain, the same candidate, in a range of time can be in different statuses and for example, Candidate 1 (for simplicity C1) in the table above, was in 4 statuses.

C1 stayed in incomplete status from/to and on this status period was not contacted so that why we have null on last column first_contact.

C1 was contacted in the next 2 statuses and we determine the first_contact checking from the activities table the minimum activity timestamps of the types PHONE, EMAIL, and SMS in the range of time C1 was in that specific status from/to. The first_contact is the first time a candidate was contacted by EMAIL PHONE or SMS.

On the last status, we have `statusTo = null` so also `firstContact` is null.

The result I'm getting now is correct but seems not efficient to me and probably can get better but have no confidence in the way to manage the change in this situation.

Comment: First I would try to eliminate `statuses_flow    LEFT JOIN statuses_flow next_status` by computing `lead(s.timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY s.candidate_id,   s.timestamp) AS "statusTo"` in the cte directly

Comment: You mean the entire thing with what you suggest 
` LEFT JOIN statuses_flow next_status ON statuses_flow.id = next_status.id
        AND statuses_flow.row_no + 1 = next_status.row_no`

or I leave the ON part

Comment: @Serg can you show me in a Pastebin what you mean I never used LEAD and have syntax error when I'm trying to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First using LEAD to eliminate an extra join. Plus a cte to precompute max id can probably also help

```
WITH sa as(
   select candidate_id, type
   from (
        SELECT candidate_id, type, row_number() OVER (partition by candidate_id ORDER BY id desc) rn
    FROM public.statuses
    ) t
   where rn = 1 and type != 'ANONYMISED'
), statuses_flow AS (
    SELECT
        c.id,
        c.study_id,
        c.site_id,
        s.type AS status_type,
        s.timestamp AS status_from,
        sa.type,
        lead(s.timestamp) OVER (partition by c.id ORDER BY s.candidate_id,
            s.timestamp) AS statusTo
    FROM
        public.candidates c
        JOIN public.statuses s ON s.candidate_id = c.id
        JOIN  sa ON sa.candidate_id = c.id
    WHERE
        c.study_id in('INIT1')
        AND c.site_id in('Test1')
        AND sa.type != 'ANONYMISED' 
)
SELECT
    statuses_flow.id, statuses_flow.study_id AS "studyId", 
    statuses_flow.site_id AS "siteId", statuses_flow.status_type AS "statusType", 
    statuses_flow.status_from AS "statusFrom", 
    statuses_flow.statusTo, 
    CASE WHEN statuses_flow.statusTo IS NULL THEN
        NULL
    ELSE
        (
        SELECT
            created_at AS first_contact
        FROM
            public.activities
        WHERE
            candidate_id = statuses_flow.id
            AND TYPE in('PHONE', 'SMS', 'EMAIL')
            AND created_at BETWEEN statuses_flow.status_from
            AND statuses_flow.statusTo ORDER BY
                created_at FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)
    END AS "first_contact"
FROM
    statuses_flow
WHERE
    statuses_flow.status_type in('PENDING_SITE', 'PENDING_CALLCENTER', 'INCOMPLETE', 'REJECTED_CALLCENTER', 'REJECTED_SITE', 'CONSENTED')
ORDER BY
    statuses_flow.id,
    statuses_flow.status_from
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=06d7821fcfdcdb02ab6c4de854febdc2) , with comparing the results.

Comment: @Jakub edited the query  added missing ` ..partition by c.id ..`  .